# My JFrame project won't paint some PNGs and will paint others even though everything is in the same directory

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have a minesweeper project that uses pngs to paint the icons for my cells. For some reason, my paint/draw methods will fill in all of the cells except mines. Everything is in the same directory.  In my code, I override paintComponent(Graphics g) from java.awt.Graphics. I then paint the cells of my minefield based on their status "opened"/"flagged"/"covered" etc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPGZW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcZg1.png)

here is the pathway of methods that are involved in my painting process:

**UPDATE: Here is a minimal reproducable example**

1. Play.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Play
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // game configs rows,cols,cellSize,#ofmines
                    int[] default_configs = {16,16,15,10};
                    
                    Configuration.loadParameters(default_configs);
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("select a cell");
                    frame.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    frame.add(new Board(Configuration.ROWS, Configuration.COLS, Configuration.MINES, statusbar));
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setTitle("Ekrem's Minefield");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
    
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Board.java

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class Board extends JPanel
{

    private Minefield minefield;
    private JLabel status;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int mines;
/**
 *  Constructor that creates a minefield, initializes values, activates mouse, and sets up size of the board
 */
    public Board(int height, int width, int mines, JLabel statusbar)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.mines = mines;
        this.minefield = new Minefield(height, width, mines);
        status = statusbar;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Configuration.BOARD_WIDTH, Configuration.BOARD_HEIGHT));
        addMouseListener(new MouseReader(this));
    }
/**
 * @param Graphics object
 */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        minefield.draw(g);
    }
    
    public Minefield getMinefield() {
        return this.minefield;
    }
    
/**
 * this method adjusts the statuses of cells based on user interaction through a mouse
 */
    public void mouseClickOnLocation(int x, int y, String button)
    {
        Object clickedCell = minefield.getCellByScreenCoordinates(x,y);
        if (clickedCell instanceof InfoCell) {
            if (button == "right") {
                if (((InfoCell)(clickedCell)).getStatus().equals("opnd")) {
                    return;
                }
                else if (((InfoCell)(clickedCell)).getStatus().equals("mrkd")) {
                    ((InfoCell)(clickedCell)).setStatus("cvrd");
                }
                else {
                    ((InfoCell)(clickedCell)).setStatus("mrkd");
        
                }
                
            }
            else if (button == "left") {
                //minefield.openCells((InfoCell)(clickedCell));
            }
        }
        if (clickedCell instanceof MineCell) {
            if (button == "right") {
                if(((MineCell)(clickedCell)).getStatus().equals("cvrd")) {
                    ((MineCell)(clickedCell)).setStatus("mrkd");
                    
                }
                else{
                    ((MineCell)(clickedCell)).setStatus("cvrd");
        
                }

            }
            else if (button == "left") {
                ((MineCell)(clickedCell)).setStatus("opnd");
            }
        }

        
    }

}
```

Configuration.java

```
public class Configuration {
    public static int ROWS;
    public static int COLS;
    public static int CELL_SIZE;
    public static int MINES;
    public static int BOARD_WIDTH;
    public static int BOARD_HEIGHT;
    public static int UNOPENED_INFOCELL_COUNT;
    
    public static void loadParameters(int[] parameters){
        ROWS = parameters[0];
        COLS = parameters[1];
        CELL_SIZE = parameters[2];
        MINES = parameters[3];
        UNOPENED_INFOCELL_COUNT = ROWS * COLS - MINES;
        BOARD_WIDTH = COLS * CELL_SIZE + 1;
        BOARD_HEIGHT = ROWS * CELL_SIZE + 1;
    }

}
```

InfoCell.java

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class InfoCell {
    private int row;
    private int column;
    private int numOfAdjacentMines = 0;
    private String status = "cvrd";
    //covered, uncovered, marked, wrongly_marked

    public InfoCell(int row, int column, int numOfAdjacentMines) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.numOfAdjacentMines = numOfAdjacentMines;
    }
    public int getRow() {
        return this.row;
    }
    public int getCol() {
        return this.column;
    }
    public void setMines(int mineCount) {
        this.numOfAdjacentMines = mineCount;
    }
    public int getNumOfAdjacentMines() {
        return this.numOfAdjacentMines;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(this.getImage(), this.getHorizontalPosition(), this.getVerticalPosition(), null);
    }
    
    public Image getImage() {
        Image image;
        if (status.equals("cvrd")) {
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/covered_cell.png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        else if(status.equals("mrkd")) {
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/marked_cell.png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        else if(status.equals("wmrkd")){
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/wrong_mark.png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        else /*(status.equals(Configuration.STATUS_OPENED))*/ {
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/info_" + this.numOfAdjacentMines + ".png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        return image; 
                
    }
    
    public int getHorizontalPosition() {
        return (column) * Configuration.CELL_SIZE;
        //Calculates and returns the pixel-level horizontal position of the top-left corner of the cell
    }
    
    public int getVerticalPosition() {
        return (row) * Configuration.CELL_SIZE;
        //Calculates and returns the pixel-level vertical position of the top-left corner of the cell
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        //Setter method for the current status of the cell. Do not hard-code the value;
        //use a Configuration parameter instead.
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

MineCell.java

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Graphics;

/**
 * 
 * @author Ekrem Kaya
 * @version 9:44 03/11
 */
public class MineCell {
/**
 * row, columnm, and status of each cell
 */
    private int row;
    private int column;
    private String status = "cvrd";
    //covered - cvrd, uncovered - opnd, marked - mrkd
/**
 * 
 * @param row vertical location of the Cell object in Minefield
 * @param column horizantal poisition of the Cell object in Minefield
 */
    public MineCell(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = row;
    }
/**
 * 
 * @param g the Graphics object passed to the cell by the Minefield class
 */
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(this.getImage(), this.getHorizontalPosition(), this.getVerticalPosition(), null);
    }
/**
 * 
 * @return this method returns an in representing the horizantal pixel location
 */
    public int getHorizontalPosition() {
        return (column) * Configuration.CELL_SIZE;
        //Calculates and returns the pixel-level horizontal position of the top-left corner of the cell
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return this method returns an in representing the vertical pixel location
     */
    public int getVerticalPosition() {
        return (row) * Configuration.CELL_SIZE;
        //Calculates and returns the pixel-level vertical position of the top-left corner of the cell
    }
/**
 * 
 * @return this method returns the status attribute of the Cell which can be covered, open, wrongly marked, or marked
 */
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
/**
 * 
 * @param status the string that represents the status of the cell
 */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        //Setter method for the current status of the cell. Do not hard-code the value;
        //use a Configuration parameter instead.
        this.status = status;
    }
/**
 * 
 * @return this returns the image from the folder that will represent the status of the cell
 */
    public Image getImage() {
        
        Image image;
        
        if(this.status.equals("mrkd")) {
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/marked_cell.png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        else if(this.status.equals("opnd")) {
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/mine_cell.png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        else /*(status.equals(Configuration.STATUS_COVERED))*/ {
            ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("img/covered_cell.png");
            image = a.getImage();
        }
        return image;
                
    }
}
```

MouseReader.java

```
/**
 * DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING IN THIS FILE
*/
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MouseReader extends MouseAdapter
{
    private Board board;

    public MouseReader(Board board)
    {
        this.board = board;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        String button = "";
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            button = "left";
        else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            button = "right";
        board.mouseClickOnLocation(e.getX(), e.getY(), button);
    }
}
```

The methods for non-mine cells and minecells are almost identical, the code ends up painting all cells except minecells. I have checked and found that each of the above methods do end up being called and that the status of the minecells are also correctly labeled.

Comment: [mcve] would be really helpful - because it "looks" like you're violating the paint chain

Comment: I would also make use of [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead of `ImageIcon` as `ImageIO` will actually throw an exception when the image can't be loaded/read unlike `ImageIcon` which fails silently

Comment: *"I override paintComponent(Graphics g) from java.awt.Graphics"* - No, you didn't.  `Graphics` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method, which leads me to assume that you mean you've overriding `paintComponent` of a `JComponent` (or subclass), which takes me right back to my first comment

Comment: `if (field[i][k] instanceof MineCell) {` casting like this kind of seems like a bad idea.  I'd instead you use an `interface` which defined a `draw` method of some kind and the make your `field` store references of those (ie `Drawable[][] fields = ....`)

Comment: I'd also look at what `getHorizontalPosition` and `getVerticalPosition` are returning as you could be painting the images off screen